# My Discord bot is Shown as Online, but does not Respond with Anything when Using Heroku

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.js

I just setup Heroku and it was very easy, however when I tested it nothing happened. Even though the bot was online, so I looked at the log in Heroku, and everything looked fine. The mongodb was connected, and it said my bot was online. I've tried restarting dyno, using a new discord token, completely restarting my app, but nothing works. Help very much appreciated!(I'm using GitHub for deploying)

Here is my Heroku Log:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEciI.png

And just in case my Procfile:

```js
worker: node main.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `workflows`?
They are very easy to use and only need 2 min of your time,
as the problem may occur from heroku when it automatically deploys the branch.

`Instructions`

1. Create a `.github` folder
2. inside that folder create a `workflows` folder
3. inside that folder create a `main.yml` file
4. insert the below code:

```
name: Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main # the branch to deploy to heroku

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12 
        with:
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}} #go to settings and under  copy your token key, then go to your repository add a secret in the settings of the repository with name `HEROKU_API_KEY` and value `your API key`
          heroku_app_name: "herokuappname" #Must be exact with yours
          heroku_email: "youremail"
```

so your path should be `.github/workflows/main.yml`

if you need further help then you can comment here also make sure to see in resources if the worker is enabled . I hope i helped

Comment: Do I have to put my token in the value part of my secret or do I put "your API key"?

Comment: no you're api key is the name and the value is the token. if you mean the bot token then you can add that on heroku when deployed.

Comment: so this is what you wanna do, go to heroku account settings -> under ssh keys -> API keys -> copy api key by revealing it -> go to github -> your bot repository -> repository settings -> secrets -> actions -> create a new secret -> name: HEROKU_API_KEY, value: "yourapikeyfromheroku"

Comment: So for example HEROKU_API_KEY: "94346329-5278-4861-b80f-04d77503c28f"

Comment: if you can't do it on your own, you could invite me for this and then remove me from the project.

Comment: I tried what you said, and it still doesn't respond

Comment: Wait I think I know what is making it not work, the terminal keeps telling me that name is undefined

Comment: look give me your app's name and the email that is with it and ill do the code for you. if you can't do it, because either the app of your's is broken or try making a new app maybe that may fix the bug

Comment: Okay I will make a new app and if it doesn't work THEN you can do it for me

Comment: Sorry for the late response, the bot still won't work on Heroku so tell me when I can add you to the heroku project

Comment: You can add me, me, username is HACKERPROTM but you could also search my name and it will be shown. Go to settings -> collaborators -> invite collaborator -> search -> brandon torreglosa or HACKERPROTM. on github this is

Comment: to add me on heroku simply Select the app in the dashboard. Click the Add collaborator button. In the New collaborator window, type my email address "brandontorreglosa@gmail.com". Click Save changes.

Comment: I added you to both, I also removed the config vars for privacy.

Comment: I found the issue, I think my config vars also needed a prefix, and now it works. I also added the heroku api key so thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
client.on('debug', console.log);
```

somewhere in your main.js.

It's most likely that you are experiencing a 429 error because Heroku uses shared IP addresses for public accounts.

If you run your bot after adding the debug line and get a 429 error type

```
kill 1
```

in the *terminal* for your bot. This will force your bot to restart and hopefully, it will work again when you re-run it.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get an error 429, but the logs had a heartbeat which was new

Answer (score 0):

If this is the first time you're using `heroku` try to look at your `package.json` then find the `engines`.

```
"engines": {
   "node": "16.x"
}
```

Comment: My package.json doesn't have the engines, but my package-lock.json does have it, and it says    "engines": {
        "node": ">=6.9.0"
      },

Comment: You need to put `engines` at `package.json` aswell

Comment: I put the engines in package.json, tested it and still no response

Comment: Did you double checked the `prefix` of yours?

Comment: Yeah everything looks fine, my prefix is in my .env file and I'm using message.js so the bot knows what the prefix is

Comment: If you add the `.env` on `.gitignore` (if you have), it will not let you use that `prefix`, you must add it on the main `index file`

Comment: I didn't use .gitignore, I'm guessing this isn't my code because it works if I host the bot locally